# C++ type traits to select between T1 and T2

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

I want a template to select from two types based on some condition. E.g.

```
struct Base {};

template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct test
{
    // e.g. here it should select T1/T2 that is_base_of<Base>
    typename select_base<T1, T2>::type m_ValueOfBaseType;
};
```

Of course to pass condition to the select_base (to make it generic) would be useful, but hard-coded solution is easier and good as well.

Here's a sample solution that I tried but it always selects T1: http://ideone.com/EnVT8

The question is how to implement the select_base template.

Comment: Your question is unclear. You want to select the base type out of the two types `T1` or `T2`, e.g if `T1` derives from `T2`, then the output type should be `T2`. Or you want to select the type which derives from a third type, say `base`?

Comment: @Nawaz: from the linked ideone, I would say `Base` is fixed and he wants to choose whichever of `T1` or `T2` derives from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**C++14** (and onwards):

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct select_base:
    std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value, T, U> {};
```

In the same vein, you can instead use this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
using select_base = std::conditional_t<std::is_base_of_v<T,Base>, T, U>;
```

The difference between these two approaches can be observed when you use them. For example, in the first case if you have to use `::type` whereas in the second, you dont. And if any dependent type involves in the usage of the first approach, you have to use `typename` as well, to assist the compiler. The second approach is free of all such noises and thus superior to the rest of the approaches in this answer.

Also, please note that you can write similar type-alias in C++11 as well.

---

**C++11**:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct select_base:
    std::conditional<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value, T, U>::type {};
//                 ^                                       ^~~~~~
```

---

**C++98**:

Conditional is easy enough:

```
template <typename bool, typename T, typename U>
struct conditional { typedef T type; };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct conditional<false, T, U> { typedef U type; };
```

`is_base_of` is slightly more complicated, an implementation is available in Boost that I will not reproduce here.

Afterwards, see C++11.

Comment: Yes, this is generic and works well, thanks! I completely forgot about non-type template parameters.

Comment: The `if_` template has been standardized as `std::conditional`.  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Answer (score 18):

If you use [`std::conditional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional) instead of `if_` class template as implemented by @Matthieu in his answer, then your solution would reduce to this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct select_base
{
   typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value, T, U>::type base_type;
};
```

Or simply this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct select_base : std::conditional<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value, T, U> {};
```

which looks even better.

The difference between these two solutions is that in the first solution you give a *programmer-friendly* name to the nested type, as I've given it `base_type`, while in the second solution the nested type is just `type` which doesn't look that programmer-friendly.

Note that in both of the above solutions, you've to use the nested type as either `select_base<T,U>::base_type` (in the first solution) or `select_base<T,U>::type` (in the second solution — and because of that, if you've use `typename` as you've written yourself in the question itself.

However, if you *instead* use template alias, defined as:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
using base_type = typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<T, Base>::value, T, U>::type;
```

then you can use `base_type<T,U>` without any nested-type and `typename` as:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct test
{
   //typename select_base<T1, T2>::type m_ValueOfBaseType; //ugly!

   base_type<T1, T2>  m_ValueOfBaseType; //better
};
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ah thanks, I can't wrap my head around this one, the name is just too weird :x (also, unless you are missing a `typedef typename` here).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Ohh just forgot that part.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip, after Matthieu's answer I was sure I'll find something similar in type_traits, and of course it is there. I suppose I have to read the docs first, because reinventing wheels is fun but non-productive.

Comment: Do we possibly miss a `using` here?