# Choose structs based on condition

Tags: c++, templates, conditional-statements

I am trying to read a las file with a header and point records. The header contains the point format information which can vary from 0 to 3 which leads to different formats with extra fields.

**LasReader.h**

```
template <typename T>
class las_reader
{
public:
    las_reader();
    las_reader(std::ifstream &FileHandle);
    ~las_reader();
private:
    las_header_reader lh; // struct to read las header info
    std::vector<T> lp; // vector of struct template T to read las points
    void lasReadHeader(std::ifstream &FileHandle);
    void lasReadPoints(std::ifstream &FileHandle);
};
```

**LasReader.cpp**

```
template <typename T>
void las_reader<T>::lasReadPoints(std::ifstream &FileHandle)
{ 
    // reserves the size of vector
    lp.resize(lh.num_pointRecords);
    FileHandle.seekg(lh.offset_pointData,std::ios::beg);
    // iterator which goes through file and reads to vector
    FileHandle.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&lp[0]),lh.num_pointRecords *sizeof(T));
}
```

Now I want to place the struct format as the template according to the condition. I tried `std::conditional` as given in the 2nd answer of [C++ type traits to select between T1 and T2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065313/c-type-traits-to-select-between-t1-and-t2) but it works on a boolean between two templates.

**EDIT**
Something to look like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U, typename V, typename W> 
struct select_format
{
    typedef typename std::conditional<std::is_base_of<T,las_points_reader>::value, T, U, V, W>::type base_type;
```

}

Comment: Reading binary data from disk straight into a struct is asking for trouble. The binary layout of the struct may vary between compilers. Why does your function seek the file back to the beginning? What if someone wants to load only from a certain part of the file onwards.

Comment: Is what you are asking, how can a vector hold elements where each element needs to be a different type?

Comment: No my question is I want the struct to be decided as template on the basis of a condition. Should be similar to the 2nd answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065313/c-type-traits-to-select-between-t1-and-t2 but on 4 typenames instead of 2

Comment: I don't see a single conditional in your code.  Could you maybe add some “pseudo code” (it need not compile) for what you aim to be able to do?

Comment: added a link for the similar kind of answer

Comment: That answer shows how to use `std::conditional` but you say you cannot use it for what you want to do.  So, what do you *want* to do?

Comment: added a piece of code to show what I want. Ofcourse does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### If you want to select `T` based on some data

Template parameters are deduced at compile-time and cannot be selected in runtime. You need to use inheritance or [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/variant.html).

### If you want to have vector of different types with pre-defined positions

Use struct.